# InvalidAuthenticityToken in Rails 5 behind Nginx using SSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, cookies, nginx, ruby-on-rails-5

I've got a really weird issue with Rails 5 (beta1) and it's preventing me from safely submitting any forms.

When running in production mode behind an Nginx (1.4.6 on Ubuntu 12.04) reverse proxy which decrypts SSL, Rails is rejecting my CSRF tokens saying they are invalid despite the fact that the correct token is being submit by the form.

Everything works fine when I turn SSL off in Nginx.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Fix by adding more headers in Nginx (`X-Forwarded-Ssl on`, `X-Forwarded-Port 443` and `X-Forwarded-Host "your hostname"`, `X-Forwarded-Proto https`). The problem was actually in the new way CSRF tokens are checked by ActionController (compares the request.base_url with the origin header)

Comment: Thanks! This problem was driving me nuts, and your fix worked.

Comment: I also was having this issue. The single line that fixed it for me was adding `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;` to the `location @puma` block

Comment: fixed this using [configuration from passenger documentation](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/standalone/reverse_proxy.html#step-2-install-and-configure-span-class-nginx-nginx-span-span-class-hidden-or-span-span-class-apache-apache-span)

Comment: Any idea why the nginx returns 400 response when adding the `proxy_set_header   Host             $host;` ?